# aplay can't see sound card on HP pavilion laptop

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

On ubuntu 19.04 after an update sound stopped. I've tried modprobe remedies redoing the downgrading/upgrading the OS back to 18.04. Everything comes up dummy output in the sound settings. Aplay reports:

```
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...
```

lspci says:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 130
    Memory at b12b0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b1290000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

alsamixer complains:

```
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory

lsmod | grep snd returns:

snd_soc_skl            86016  0
snd_soc_skl_ipc        65536  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       24576  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_dsp        32768  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_sst_ipc        16384  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_acpi           16384  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_core          241664  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          45056  0
snd_hda_codec         126976  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           81920  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_skl
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  7 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    81920  10 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

The only advice online I haven't followed so far is looking in my bios because when I boot into the bios there are no options I can see and access that effect the hardware.

Here are some links I found that didn't work for me.

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html

https://docs.slackware.com/howtos:hardware:audio_and_snd-hda-intel#how_to_find_the_right_options

["Dummy Output" No sound in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914463/dummy-output-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04)

[How to fix "No Soundcards Found"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57810/how-to-fix-no-soundcards-found)

[Xubuntu 17.10 - no sound, alsa says no such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004021/xubuntu-17-10-no-sound-alsa-says-no-such-file-or-directory/1064860)

Comment: Please clarify by what you mean with "*downgrading/upgrading the OS back to 18.04*", did you re-install or what?  *downgrading packages for a whole release isn't an easy task, thus I suspect this is your issue*  I also see a number of non-Ubuntu sources tried?  did you actually try any official troubleshooting?  eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: pulseaudio + reboot got it. Changing the whole release version wasn't an easy task it took a couple of days. Thanks